# Liberar espaço de memoria do servidor quando estiver ocioso

Tags: golang

Tenho um código mais ou menos com essa estrutura:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/",taltal)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080",nil)
}

func check(err error){
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func taltal(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    if r.Method == "GET"{
        t,err := template.ParseFiles("request.html")
        check(err)
        t.Execute(w,nil)
    }
}
```

Esse código simplesmente cria um servidor com o que quer que tenha no arquivo `request.html` e ele executa em `localhost:8080`, veja que as rotas eu defino em `http.HandleFunc("/",taltal)`.

Eu pude reparar que no gerenciador de tarefas, mesmo quando o servidor estava ocioso, o uso de memoria nunca diminuía, só aumentava de acordo com a quantidade de chamadas que eu fazia para o servidor.

Estado inicial:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apos realizar algumas requisições:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o uso de memoria nunca diminui, mesmo quando o servidor esta ocioso.

Como eu libero a memoria que não esta mais sendo usada e ao mesmo tempo não travo o servidor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando o GC do Go libera memória, não quer dizer que ele retorne ela para o OS, essa memória fica disponível para seu programa reutilizar e somente após um tempo como disponível, ela é liberada para o OS. Em todo caso, você pode usar [FreeOSMemory](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#FreeOSMemory) para forçar esse processo (não sei como esta no Windows, no Linux funciona)

> FreeOSMemory forces a garbage collection followed by an attempt to
>   return as much memory to the operating system as possible. (Even if
>   this is not called, the runtime gradually returns memory to the
>   operating system in a background task.)